# create a bar by series of divs with the width of div in pixel change by model in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
array = [1,3 5,6,9,3,5,7]

<div style="float:left; height:5px; width:{{item}}px" ng-repeat="item in array"></div>
```

I want to create a bar by series of divs with the width of div in pixel change by the value of item. Please help, thanks!

Comment: I assume that you have created controller which requires in angular.  So just you can modified it as per my answer.

Comment: Now check, you are missing comma (,)  in declaration of an array.

Comment: It is work with (") not ('). Thanks so much!

Comment: [Here is the ngRepeat reference](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat) for anyone wanting more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$scope.myArray = [1,3,5,6,9,3,5,7]

<div style="float:left; height:5px; width:{{item}}px" ng-repeat="item in myArray"></div>
```

Comment: Have tried: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number in myArray